# SVG и ImageButton

Tags: android, svg, imagebutton

Хочу использовать SVG для отображения состояния звука включен/выключен для различных экранов. Использую библиотеку: `https://github.com/thinkingcow/svg-android-2`
Устанавливаю SVG картинку на кнопку:

```
SVG svg;
svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.speaker_white_off);
Drawable drawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
btnSound.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Разметка для кнопки в xml файле:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnSound"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:background="#2D2D2D"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_silent_mode_off" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Выдает картинку очень большого размера, а хотелось бы как-то этот размер скорректировать. Посмотрел в библиотеке есть метод resizePicture, но он возвращает объект Picture, а как его использовать для установления кнопки я не знаю. Как можно изменить размеры картинки SVG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, для использования векторных изображений вам не требуется сторонняя библиотека.
Во-вторых, если кнопка должна иметь два состояния, то лично я использую `ToggleButton`, как это работает?

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_button_state"
        android:text=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn="" />
```

В качестве `background` передаем разметку `toggle_button_state`. Код разметки `toggle_button_state`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_dynamic_on" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_dynamic_off" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Если состояние `ToggleButton` активное - `true` отображается картинка `ic_dynamic_on`, если неактивное - `false` отображается `ic_dynamic_off`.

Касательно `SVG`: Все делаете стандартными инструментами `Android Studio`, собираете нужные вам векторные изображения в одной папке на вашем компьютере. В студии на папку `res` кликаете правой кнопкой мыши и `res -> New -> Vector Asset` в открывшемся окне переключаетесь на `Local file (SVG, PSD)` и в графе `Path` указываете путь к вашему `SVG` изображению на компьютере. В графе `Name` задаете имя файлу в графе `Size` устанавливаете нужное вам соотношение размеров (по стандарту `24x24dp`) и делаете нажимаете `Next -> Finish`, готово! В вашей директории `Drawable` появляется `SVG` картинка.

P.S. Если вам все же удобнее использовать `ImageButton` то векторные изображения задавайте через `srcCompat`:

```
app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_lock_silent_mode_off" />
```

Comment: В моё случае возникла ошибка с обработкой SVG. Пока не нашел решение, Вы не сталкивались с таким?

Comment: @i_burykin, сталкивался, иконки брал отсюда www.flaticon.com